# How to define the intersection product of a curve with itself: $(C\cdot C)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, terminology, algebraic-curves, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I'm reading through Positivity in Algebraic Geometry by Lazarsfeld, and it defines the intersection product for bundles $L$ and (Cartier) divisors $D$ on a complete, irreducible complex variety $X$, via chern classes (the specifics of the definition are not *necessarily* relevant to this question).

However, in (for example) in exercise 1.2.31, it mentions the intersection product of an *irreducible curve on a smooth projective surface* with itself: $(C\cdot C)$. How should one interpret this? It also makes mention of the sheaf $O_X(mC)$, but I am not sure what this entails either -- it seems neither to be a twisted sheaf nor a sheaf $O_X(mD)$ for a divisor $D$, again unless we can consider $C$ as a Cartier divisor.

**Questions:** Am I supposed to view $C$ as a Cartier divisor here? If so, how? Specifically, how should I define $(C\cdot C)$ and $O_X(mC)$?

Comment: Oops this is $O_X(-mC)$, for $O_X(mC)$ it is the opposite $f\in O_X(mC)(U)$ if $f\in O_X(U-C)$ and for $p\in U\cap C$, $f I_p^m\subset O_{X,p}$ where $I_p=\ker(O_{X,p}\to O_{C,p})$

Comment: The geometry here is really this: you can change one of the Cs to a curve C' upto linear equivalence such that C and C' intersect transversally and now the self-intersection number of C is really the number of intersections of C and C' (counted with multiplicity).

Comment: A good book to read about this topic is complex algebraic surfaces by Beauville, the first pages explain in an excellent way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a disclaimer: I'm a bit rusty with algebraic geometry, so apologies for inaccuracies.

An irreducible curve on a smooth projective surface is by definition a prime divisor which corresponds to an effective Cartier divisor since the surface is nice enough (it is smooth). In particular, you view $\mathcal{O}_X(mC)$ as the line bundle of this divisor $mC$ (see e.g. Vakil or Hartshorne for a definition).

The intersection product can e.g. be defined as $(C \cdot C) = \deg{\mathcal{O}_S(C)|_C}$ where $C \subseteq S$ is the curve on the surface. There is also a more general notion of the intersection product of invertible sheaves:

**Definition.** Let $\mathcal{F} \in \mathbf{Coh}_X$ be a coherent sheaf with proper support of dimension $\leq n$ over a projective $k$-variety and $\mathcal{L}_1, \dots, \mathcal{L}_n$ be invertible sheaves on $X$. Then, $$ (\mathcal{L}_1 \cdot \mathcal{L_2} \cdot \cdots \cdot \mathcal{L_n} \cdot \mathcal{F}) = \sum_{\{i_1, \dots, i_m \} \subseteq \{1,\dots,n \}} (-1)^m \chi(X, \mathcal{L}_{i_1}^{\vee} \otimes \dots \otimes \mathcal{L}_{i_m}^{\vee} \otimes \mathcal{F})$$ is called *intersection of $\mathcal{L}_1, \dots, \mathcal{L}_n$ with $\mathcal{F}$*.

For effective Cartier divisors $C,D$ on $X$, we interpret/define $$C \cdot D = (C \cdot D) = (\mathcal{O}_X(C) \cdot \mathcal{O}_X(D) \cdot \mathcal{O}_X).$$ You can e.g. find this viewpoint wonderfully written in Vakil's *Rising Sea*, chapter 20. In that regard, the fact $(C \cdot C) = \deg{\mathcal{O}_S(C)|_C}$ appears as *Exercise 20.2.A*.